# How to prevent running the __main__ guard when using execfile?

Tags: python, program-entry-point, exit

The BDFL posted in 2003 [an article about how to write a Python main function](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=4829). His example is this:

```
import sys
import getopt

class Usage(Exception):
    def __init__(self, msg):
        self.msg = msg

def main(argv=None):
    if argv is None:
        argv = sys.argv
    try:
        try:
            opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv[1:], "h", ["help"])
        except getopt.error, msg:
             raise Usage(msg)
        # more code, unchanged
    except Usage, err:
        print >>sys.stderr, err.msg
        print >>sys.stderr, "for help use --help"
        return 2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

The reason for the optional argument `argv` to `main()` is, "We change `main()` to take an optional `argv` argument, which allows us to call it from the interactive Python prompt."

He explains the last line of his code like this:

> Now the `sys.exit()` calls are annoying: when `main()` calls `sys.exit()`,
>   your interactive Python interpreter will exit! The remedy is to let
>   `main()`'s return value specify the exit status. Thus, the code at the
>   very end becomes
>
> ```
> if __name__ == "__main__":
>     sys.exit(main())
> ```
>
> and the calls to `sys.exit(n)` inside `main()` all become `return n`.

However, when I run Guido's code in a Spyder console, it kills the interpreter. What am I missing here? Is the intention that I only `import` modules that have this type of `main()`, never just executing them with `execfile` or `runfile`? That's not how I tend to do interactive development, especially given that it would require me to remember to switch back and forth between `import foo` and `reload(foo)`.

I know I can catch the `SystemExit` from `getopt` or try to use some black magic to detect whether Python is running interactively, but I assume neither of those is the BDFL's intent.

Comment: "Is the intention that I only import modules that have this type of main(), never just executing them with execfile or runfile?"  Yes, I believe so.  Why do you want to use `execfile` or `runfile`?

Comment: Yes, you need to `import` it. When you exec/run it, `__name__` is `__main__` and the `sys.exit` at the end does run.

Comment: @BrenBarn asks, "Why do you want to use `execfile` or `runfile`?" Let's say I'm trying to write a moderately complex function. I'll try running it a couple times in the console, go back to the source file and make some edits, hit F5 to execute that file, and then test it from the console again. `import` doesn't work well in this context. Is this not typical?

Comment: @kuzzooroo: I think what's not typical is the combination of wanting to do that *and* wanting to use that function interactively *but still* have the same script be runnable as main.  Once you have imported the script once, you can use `reload` to reload it.

Comment: At most, this is an issue with your IDE, which closes its embedded interpreter when the code it runs calls `sys.exit`. Perhaps it should silently catch that exception at the top level and let you continue to do stuff interactively. Alternatively, you could abandon the program return value and just call `main()` from your `if __name__ == "__main__"` block without the `sys.exit` wrapping.

Comment: If I were starting this project from scratch I would follow one of @Blckknght's suggestions, giving up on the sys.exit wrapping.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your options are to not use `execfile` or to pass in a different `__name__` value as a global:

```
execfile('test.py', {'__name__': 'test'})
```

The default is to run the file as a script, which means that `__name__` is set to `__main__`.

The article you cite only applies to `import`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to handle it, which I alluded to briefly in the question, is to try to detect if you're in an interactive context. I don't believe this can be done portably, but here it is in case it's helpful to someone:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if 'PYTHONSTARTUP' in os.environ:
        try:
            main() # Or whatever you want to do here
        except SystemExit as se:
            logging.exception("")
    else:
        sys.exit(main())
```